# Writing to .log file with std::fstream::app on linux

Tags: c++, linux, file

I'm trying to write some logs in a .log file.
My code works for windows.

- Tested in Visual Studio 2015
- Dev-C ++

When I login to linux and run the code, the file outcome.log remains empty after calling this function a lot of times.

```
bool write_log(string origin, string user, string outcome) {
```

This is to take the number of logs from some other function

```
    int log_id = get_log();
    set_logs(++log_id);
```

Now I open the file with fstream:

```
    fstream logs("outcome.log", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::app);
    if (logs.is_open()) {
```

Converting the log from int to string in order to push it into my string:

```
        string log, myline;
        stringstream converter; //convertng from int to string
        converter << log_id;
        converter >> log;
```

Connecting all of the pieces to myline, and then insert it to `outcome.log` :

```
        myline = log + "|" + origin + "|" + user + "|" + outcome + "|"; //connecting pieces
        logs << endl << myline; //inserting string to file
        logs.close();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        logs.close();
        cout << "Error, cannot open log file." << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting std::fstream:app

In another function that I used std::fstream::out where I overwrite the file, it works.

Comment: Test the state of the stream after writing to it.

Comment: I'd try to open the file for output: `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app`. There shouldn't be a need to open the file for input when specifying `std::ios_base::app` (`std::ios_base::in` is needed when using `std::ios_base::out` alone if the file shouldn't be truncated). Note, that opening a file for each log output is hideously inefficient: unless there are extremely few log outputs you'd be better off keeping the file open.

Comment: With `fstream::out` it seems to work, but I cant use `getline()` if I want to. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work on linux but it does on windows?

Comment: You probably need to seek before writing (because you have read).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf seek to where I want to write?

Comment: Yes. ]]]]]]]]]]